# Error with Flink 0.10.1

Tags: maven, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flinkml

With flink 0.10.1 in local I can't connect with jobmanager due the following error:

```
Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:49789] has failed,    address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [scala.Option; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2062608324514658839, local class serialVersionUID = -114498752079829388].
```

And my pom.xml:

```
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1-hadoop1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1-hadoop1</version>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-ml</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1-hadoop1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

With flink 0.9.1 works fine ... What I'm missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the following:
On the flink download page there are several links to Flink project(binaries and source)
I had downloaded the normal ones without hadoop because is for testing purposes in my local and I don't using hadoop. 
But I dont't now why its need the hadoop ones with scala  I have downloaded:
Hadoop 2.7.0    with scala 2.10 and it works.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a version miss match, ie, that you have old 0.9.1 binaries in your code base... Try to clean your maven cache via

```
cd ~/.m2/repositories/org/apache/flink
rm -rf *
```

Afterward, rebuild your project: `mvn -DskipTests clean package`

Comment: How do you start JobManager and submit your program? Are you sure that the binaries of your Flink cluster are 0.10.1 and not 0.9.1 any more? I guess you download Flink binaries, right? Or did you build Flink from the source code?

Comment: I start a local Flik Server with "start-local.bat" I submit the program by: `  final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment
   .createRemoteEnvironment(Messages.getString("Job.host").trim(),
      6123, Messages.getString("Job.JobJar"));`

Comment: And I know is 0.10.1 because the log:  -  Starting JobManager (Version: 0.10.1, Rev:2e9b231, Date:22.11.2015 @ 12:41:12 CET)

Comment: And yes i I have download the binaries

Comment: Try to get your environment via `ExecutionEnvironment getExecutionEnvironment()` -- this will create the correct environment for you automatically if you start Flink via `start-local`.